# How to get the latest 3 books from each author using django

Tags: sql, django, django-queryset

Using the following django models:

```
class Author(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   age = models.IntegerField()

class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author)
    pubdate = models.DateField()
    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-pubdate')
```

How can i get the **five latest books published by each author**?

I had considered iterate each author and get books published by the author slicing to 5.

```
for a in Author.objects.all():
    books = Book.objects.filter(author = a )[:5]
    print books #and/or process the entries...
```

But, if the tables has a lot of records (maybe thousands of books), this could be slow and inefficient.

So, is there any other way to accomplish this with django (or a sql query) ?

Comment: I think this is a very good question but I couldn't find a good efficient solution for it.
what @Lapin-Blanc has said is working, but there should a be a way optimized version too. hope to be found.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest :

```
for a in Author.objects.all():
    books = a.book_set.all().order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
    print books #and/or process the entries...
```

or, if the order should always be the same, as you define Meta,

```
    books = a.book_set.all()[:5]
```

should do the trick

Comment: That's going to get you n queries. Using SQL would be much better.

Comment: for a chain in case of a big query, this may help to be faster.
```from itertools import chain; def itertools_chain_from_iterable(lsts): return list(chain.from_iterable(lsts))```

Answer (score 1):

If you're worried about the speed of the query, build an index on your pubdate field:

```
pubdate = models.DateField(db_index=True)
```

This should avoid scanning the entire table each time you run the query.

The SQL, in postgres, would be something like:

```
select b1.name, b1.author
from books b1
where b1.id in (
    select b2.id
    from books b2
    where b1.author = b2.author
    order by b2.pubdate desc
    limit 3)
order by b1.author, b1.name
```

Comment: well im using mysql, and This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'

Comment: I wouldn't worry about writing the query in SQL.  With a large table, you'll see the biggest benefit from just building an index.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had‍‍ `3 authors` and each of which had more than at least `300 posts`.
I tested two approaches and the difference is eye catching!
according to what `django-debug-toolbar` showed, first approach it had `3 similar queries` which the `3` is the number of authors here and it takes a total of `8 queries (+180 ms)` and `CPU (400 - 800 ms)`, but the second one takes a total of `5 queries (+80 ms)` and `CPU (+70 - 90 ms)`.

- also I see there is one extra query `SELECT ... FROM author` which I couldn't figure it out why it had been produced it seems not to be used at all.

```py
from .models import Author, Po‍‍st
```

### The simplest and most familiar approach

```py
from itertools import chain

authors = Author.objects.all().prefetch_related("posts")

posts = list(chain.from_iterable(author.posts.order_by("-created")[:3]
             for author in authors)
        )
```

### The more complicated and unfamiliar approach

```py
from django.db.models import OuterRef, Prefetch, Subquery

subquery = Subquery(
        Post.objects.filter(author__id=OuterRef("author__id"))
        .order_by("-created")
        .values_list("id", flat=True)[:4]
)

authors = Author.objects.all().prefetch_related(
    Prefetch("posts", queryset=Post.objects.filter(id__in=subquery))
)

posts = list(chain.from_iterable(source.posts.all()
            for source in feed_sources)
)
```

### If you just need the Posts and not the Authors:

the following way of fetching data does one less query and only returns the posts.

```py
subquery = Subquery(
    Post.objects.filter(author__id=OuterRef("author__id"))
    .order_by("-created")
    .values_list("id", flat=True)[:4]
)

posts = (
    Post.objects.select_related("author")
    .exclude(author=an_author)
    .filter(id__in=subquery)
)
```